# Explaining Low-Degree Extension in layman terms

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I am trying to learn the sumcheck protocol used in different interactive zero knowledge proof systems, however I can't move forward due to my little understanding of Low-Degree Extension (see [Chapter 5](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~danama/courses/pcp-mit/3-sum-check.pdf)).

- What is it?
- What is the problem it solves?
- How does it work?